# How to update global git hooks for the repo?

Tags: git, version-control, githooks

When I update global git hooks, and make `git init` in repo hooks don't get updated. How to update them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run:

```
git config --global init.templatedir 'hooks_location'
```

Comment: It is set already. `git config --global --get init.templatedir` returns this folder. But hooks don't get updated after init. What is interesting new files added, but existing don't change.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out according to docs subsequent init in repo only add new files from template dir, but don’t update existing.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the first `git init` from your local repo, the `git` will copy the global hooks into the `.git/hooks` directory of the git repo you are working **only if it's not there**.

Solution is, delete the hook from `.git/hooks` directory of your local repository.